# How to correctly process XSL transformation in IE and get result as a document fragment

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, xslt

I need to do XSL transformation in the browser using JavaScript.

When i'm doing this in the modern browsers, such as FF or Chrome i can do something like this:

```
     var proc = new XSLTProcessor();
     proc.importStylesheet(xslDoc);
     return proc.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, targetDocument);
```

But with IE i can only transform to a new document

```
     var newDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
     xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject(xslDoc, newDoc);
     return newDoc;
```

... or transform to text

```
     return xmlDoc.transformNode(xslDoc);
```

Transforming to text leading to huge perfomace issues (i need to append the result to my current document's DOM tree), transforming to new doc leading to doing adopt/importNode at last.

Is there a better way of doing XSL transformation in IE with further appending result to a DOM tree?

Comment: I realize this question is a few months old, and I'm not sure my solution is quite what you are after, but perhaps my solution to a very similar question I posted will help folks who end up looking for answers here. Here's a link to my SO question and answer that worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353522/xsl-processing-a-fragment-in-ie

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea ... why not add this line to your xml file :

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="your_stylesheet_file.xsl"?>
```

like shown here : http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp

This would let the browser do the transformation and then you'll load this xml in a iframe that you would parse ?

```
<iframe src="your.xml" onload="parse_it()" ></iframe>
```